# Convert unknown type generic list to array

Tags: java, arrays, generics, reflection

I'm doing a mapping using reflection.

With reflection I can know if each of the the `Field`s of a Class refers to an attribute of type "array", and also I can get the Class with the type of the array.

Now, I want to *set* the value of the field of an object. Now, for some reason, I can get the data to fill the object field, but it's not in the form of an array. Is, instead, a `Collection<?>`.

Just to make it easy to visualize, I have some code like that:

```
/** create a new T instance, with the data taken from something*/
<T> T convert(Class<T> cls, Object something) {
    T obj = cls.newInstance();
    for (Field field : cls.getFields()) {
        if (field.getType().isArray()) {
            Class<?> arrayType = field.getType().getComponentType();
            Collection<?> collection = this.getData(arrayType, something);

            Object array = CONVERT(collection);

            field.set(obj, arrayData);
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the day, I need to convert a `Collection<?>` object to (hypotetically) a `?[]` object, where "?" is dinamically correct.

I know there is `collData.toArray()`, but it builds an `Object[]`, witch is incompatible; and I know there is `collData.toArray(T[])`, but I have no idea of how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 2):

As you already have a component type, use [Array.newInstance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29):

```
Object[] array = collection.toArray(
                    (Object[])Array.newInstance(arrayType, collection.size()));
field.set(obj, array);
```

Comment: `Object array = collection.toArray(Array.newInst...);` as the type is *not* an Object array.

Comment: @JoopEggen, whatever. Any non-primitive array can be upcasted to `Object[]`. For this code it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Or do it the following way, which is easier to understand. Create an array and provide it as parameter to `colleation.toArray` :

```
Object[] array = collection.toArray(new Object[collection.size()] );
field.set(obj, array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection as a toArray() function that return an array of what the Collection is filled.
From the java doc :

```
String[] y = x.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Yes, and if you're not a fool, you can change it as you want...
Object[] y = x.toArray(new Object[0]);